# Correlation between velocity and homogeneity of spacetime and isotropy of space

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, symmetry, velocity, relative-motion

Considering only inertial frames of reference and constant velocities, does the fact that any velocity, with the exception for the speed of light in a vacuum, can be transformed, via an accurate transformation, in any other velocity have something to do with the isotropic property of space and the homogeneity of spacetime?

In particular, in order to maintain this property of velocity, is it necessary that both space and spacetime are respectively isotropic and homogeneous, or is it sufficient that just one of these properties is verified, or maybe none are? Why?

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

The isotropy of space, the assumption that space is the same in all directions, is one part of what you need for the speed of light to be the same in all directions.

The homogeneity of time - the assumption that clocks run at the same rate everywhere - is the other part.

These assumptions allow you to do the thought experiments that tell you how space and time must be related so that the speed of light is the same for observers in different inertial frames.

Without these assumptions you would have difficulty saying what you mean by the speed of light.